# Googlepredictionapi package in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, google-prediction, r-package

When I try to install the googlepredictionapi_0.1.tar.gz package in R it says:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'googlepredictionapi' ...
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
* removing 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/googlepredictionapi'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/googlepredictionapi'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "F:/R_working_Directory/googlepredictionapi_0.1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘F:/R_working_Directory/googlepredictionapi_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
Warning messages:
1: package ‘arules’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
2: package ‘clValid’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
3: package ‘ROCR’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
4: package ‘gplots’ was built under R version 3.1.3
```

I used the following code as given on the google site:

```
install.packages("googlepredictionapi_0.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Even if i go to Tool --> Install Package --> Browse--> select package, its throwing the same error.

I am using the latest R-studio version

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just created a github repo with files from the archive: https://github.com/byapparov/googlepredictionapi

You can install it with devtools:

```
devtools:install_github("byapparov/googlepredictionapi")
```

But package itself seems to be obsolete, so possibly not very useful in its current state.